# Charts add multiple series from datatable with 3 series

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, charts

```
  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select p.mn as dta,p.quan as 
    quan,i.quan,iss.quan from purchase p join inward i on p.mn=i.nm join issue iss on p.mn = iss.nm where p.pid = 4 and i.pid = 4 and iss.pid = 4", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    chart1.DataSource = dt;           
    chart1.Series["Purchase"].XValueMember = "mn";
  chart1.Series["Purchase"].YValueMembers ="quan";
```

i try it but chart is not generated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After setting the DataSource you also need to bind:

```
chart1.DataBind();
```

You will also need to set the `XValueMember` and `YValueMember` for all other `Series`.

You should call `DataBind()` whenever you have added or changed datapoints!